# cant call function whith if statement

Tags: jquery

```
$('#link-1').click(function(e) {
    $link_1 = true;
    window.open('<?php echo $deliverLink1; ?>');
    myAjax();
});

$('#link-2').click(function(e) {
    $link_2 = true;
    myAjax2();
    window.open('<?php echo $deliverLink2; ?>');

});

    if( $link_1 && $link_2){
     setTimeout(function() {
        $('#download-now-button').removeClass('not-allowed');
        $("i").removeClass("fa-lock").addClass("fa-unlock-alt");
        $("button.locked-button").removeClass("locked-button").addClass("unlocked-button");
        $("a.button-generator").attr("href", "<?php echo  $deliverFlink; ?>");
        }, 3000);
    }
```

I want to run the function, when both ids are clicked, but it doesn´t work, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You seem to have code to track if one or the other link has been clicked, so just do `if( $link_1 && $link_2)`... Also, use `true` and `false`, not `''` and `'1'`...

Comment: òk, I edited it, but it still doesnt works

Comment: When does your `if` run? If it's just running at the start, it isn't going to check again. You need to run the check whenever `$link_1` or `$link_2` change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap some function call around your if block and have both of your click events call that same function, e.g.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var $link_1, $link_2;
  $('#link-1').click(function(e) {
    $link_1 = true;
    myAjax();
  });

  $('#link-2').click(function(e) {
    $link_2 = true;
    myAjax();
  });

   function myAjax() {
      if(!$link_1 || !$link_2) return;
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#download-now-button').removeClass('not-allowed');
        $("i").removeClass("fa-lock").addClass("fa-unlock-alt");
        $("button.locked-button").removeClass("locked-button").addClass("unlocked-button");
        $("a.button-generator").attr("href", "<?php echo  $deliverFlink; ?>");
      }, 3000);
   }
});
```

It's worth noting you may also want to either disable the click events or check the setTimeout hasn't already been called to prevent the timeout being triggered multiple times.